# Is there a way to pass an aggregate sum total to a package level variable?

Tags: variables, ssis, global-variables, aggregate-functions, aggregate

Ok, I'm fairly new to SSIS and am trying to convert a flat file from one system into a file that is importable into another system.

Part of this file conversion is the utilization of a header record. The header record is comprised of some fixed components and some dynamic components. The dynamic components are the record count and the payment amount ("PAYAMT" in the expression below). I'm attempting to use the Header Property Expression to append the header to the detail records.

"00                " + REPLICATE("0",6-LEN((DT_STR,6,1252) @[User::RecordCountA1200])) + (DT_STR,6,1252) @[User::RecordCountA1200] + "PAYAMT" + "P1200000000000000000000                    "

The payment amount field is a data type of currency. My first thought was to use the aggregate transformation and store it in a recordset destination. My aggregate worked to give me the correct sum, but the variable can only be stored as an object and not a numerical data type as I was originally expecting. I would like to take the sum of the PayAmount for all of the records and put it into a user defined variable called SumAmountA1200.

Is it possible to store a value from an aggregate transformation into some other type of transformation and turn it into a package level variable? Should I go about doing this another way? Any feedback is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option for this is to use a Script Transformation connected to your Aggregate Transformation.

You can only access SSIS Variables in the pre/post execute phase of a Data Flow. Because of this limitation, what your script is going to do is perform whatever logic in the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` event. In your very specific case, there will only be 1 row sent and you would want to assign the value from the Row to a class scoped member variable.

In the PostExecute method, you would then assign the Variable's value to be the member variable's value.

### Sample code

This script is a Script Transformation acting as a destination. I have checked the Variable as a read/write (User::ExternalVariable) and on the Input/Output tab, I selected the column from the Aggregate (`Column`).

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

/// <summary>
/// This is the class to which to add your code.  Do not change the name, attributes, or parent
/// of this class.
/// </summary>
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    long memberVariable;

    /// <summary>
    /// Can update the package's Variable here
    /// </summary>
    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        //this.Variables.ExternalVariable = this.memberVariable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assign a row's value to the class level variable.
    /// Cannot assign to the 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Row">The row that is currently passing through the component</param>
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {

        this.memberVariable = Row.Column;
        // this results in a runtime error
        // The collection of variables locked for read and write access is not available outside of PostExecute.
        //this.Variables.ExternalVariable = 1111L;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt reply. This helped me out tremendously @billinkc!